# Doctrine Add column onSchemaCreateTable Event

Tags: events, doctrine, symfony4

I have some ManyToMany table relations.

I want to add a new column "created_at" automatically.

Following Symfony and Doctrine Documentation, i tired this :

*app/config/services_dev.yaml*

```
[...]
    App\Event\Listener\ManyToManyListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onSchemaCreateTable }
```

*app/src/Event/Listener/ManyToManyListener.php*

```
[.....]

class ManyToManyListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ['onSchemaCreateTable'];
    }

    public function onSchemaCreateTable(SchemaCreateTableEventArgs  $event)
    {
        $columns = $event->getTable()->getColumns();

        if (count($columns) <= 2 && !array_key_exists("created_at", $columns)) {
            $tableName = $event->getTable()->getName();
            $sql = "ALTER TABLE $tableName ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;";
            $event->addSql($sql);
              //dump($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

I can dump my SQL code inside, it works.

I also tried this code (inside the if statement)

```
$event->getTable()->addColumn(
                "created_at",
                "datetime",
                ["default" => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"]
            );
```

This never execute the SQL statement.
For example, while `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`, I can't see my query.

Comment: can you rephrase question, you dont want to alter table when creating it. All you need to do is add extra column which you can do easily by adding new key. Event has another  columns variable which you can access via $event->getColumns(), you may try to set your column there and see if it works.

Comment: Hi @MaulikParmar, I tried with the `getColumns` method but I can't add key in the result.
Where did you mean I could add that key ?

Comment: If you look at the source of the SchemaCreateTableEventArgs, event object has referenced columns field too, passed from doctrine. Apart from that as I suggested you do not want to alter table as it is not created at when this function is hooked. What you need to do is get doctrine service and alter metadata of table on your if condition. That will reflect table state in service container context and when sql is built to create table it will pick up that table metadata. Generally such meta is parsed from yaml or annotations, hope this will guide you getting things on right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through doctrine code and I understood that it was impossible to do what I wanted with those event because Event are dispatched AFTER the code path through columns, for example in `Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform`

```
    if ($this->_eventManager !== null && $this->_eventManager->hasListeners(Events::onSchemaCreateTable)) {
        $eventArgs = new SchemaCreateTableEventArgs($table, $columns, $options, $this);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatchEvent(Events::onSchemaCreateTable, $eventArgs);

        if ($eventArgs->isDefaultPrevented()) {
            return array_merge($eventArgs->getSql(), $columnSql);
        }
    }
```

So the only way with this event would have been to `preventDefault` and create the SQL myself.

---

Looking through code, I found a better way :
I modify the schema generated by the `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool->getSchemaFromMetadata`

Not sure it's the best way but it perfectly works.

```
    App\EventSubscriber\ManyToManyListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postGenerateSchema }
```

```
class SchemaGeneratorListener
{
    public function postGenerateSchema(GenerateSchemaEventArgs $event)
    {
        $tables = $event->getSchema()->getTables();

        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $columns = $table->getColumns();
            if (count($columns) <= 2 && !array_key_exists("created_at", $columns)) {
                $event->getSchema()->getTable($table->getName())->addColumn(
                    "created_at",
                    'datetime',
                    ["default" => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"]
                );
            }
        }
    }

}
```